# How to use Console.readkey(); with if statements

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a script that says either 1, 2, or 3 based on which of those numbers you press, but I don't know how to make the types the same,`Console.readkey();` doesn't want to give me an integer :/

```
int level = Console.ReadKey();

switch ( level)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `Console.WriteLine(level)`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx describes what is returned by Console.ReadKey()

Comment: Also, note that the "code snippet" feature of SO is just for web code (like javascript, html, etc.), and not for c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReadKey method returns [ConsoleKeyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type. 
So, your code should look like this:

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo level = Console.ReadKey();
        switch (level.KeyChar)
        {
            case '1':
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                break;
            case '2':
                Console.WriteLine("2");
                break;
            case '3':
                Console.WriteLine("3");
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your variable type for the user input to a string, and change ´ReadKey´ to ´ReadLine´ (or add ´.ToString()´ to the ´ReadKey()´), then you can just put double quotes for the cases like this:

```
        string level = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (level)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine("2");
                break;
            case "3":
                Console.WriteLine("3");
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```